# Error when type casting. Confusion

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

```
double d = 43.56;
int m = d;
cout<<(char *)&m<<endl; //works fine, it prints: + = 43
cout<<(char *)m<<endl; //this doesn't work, char can't be made into a  pointer
cout<<reinterpret_cast<char *>(&m)<<endl; //works fine, prints: +
cout<<static_cast<char *>(&m)<<endl; //Does not work
```

My question is, why the last line of code doesn't work?

Compiler error message: invalid static_cast from int* to type char*

Shouldn't static_cast be able to convert this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you expecting it to print `43` as string?

Comment: I don't understand.  Why doesn't `(char *) m` work?  We use it frequently in embedded systems to assign addresses of hardware components to pointers.

Comment: You may be confusing casting with the available overloads of `operator<<`.  For example `cout` will print a `char *` as a string; but `void *` as a pointer.

Comment: all 4 `cout` lines are bogus. Why do you want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) is the complete list of what can be done with `static_cast`. And
there is no option to cast pointer to one class to pointer to another non related class. Simply because this is not a standard C++ behavior.
However one can still use the c-style cast, `reinterpret_cast` or even "casting" with `union`.